# How iterate through lists in lists in Python, unknows dir depth?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, subdirectory

I have an API I'm accessing, which has a deep folder structure. I don't know the depth of the folder structure(definitely more than 4 levels and each folder has a different depth) but I want to get all folder, subfolder names and put them in a dict. As each folder has a name and id and I only can access the folder with the id, but need to match the name to make it usable.
I'm still far from being an experienced coder so I hope someone can help me with this. As I came across this issue multiple times with different APIs.
How should I for-loop when I don't know how many levels of subfolders there are?

```
folder_ids = []
folder_names = []
folders_dict = {}

response_list = client.get_asset_children(assetid) # Get subfolder and files from asset with API
assets = response_list.results

for item in assets:
    folder_ids.append(item['id'])
    folder_names.append(item['name'])

folder_dict.update(dict(zip(folder_names, folder_ids)))
```

Comment: This looks like a good moment to go and read about [recursion](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/recursion)
[also see this about folder trees in python](https://www.pythoncentral.io/series/python-recursive-file-and-directory-manipulation/)

Comment: Thank you for that very helpful links. The first one, to call the function in the function worked. Sadly it takes 40 seconds to scan everything so very long, but it's a start :) Do you think there is a way to make it faster?  I posed the Recursive Function as slow solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is super slow "around 40seconds" but it's the first solution that worked. I hope you guys can help me to solve this puzzle with faster code.
I used a recursive function.

```
def get_subassets(assetid): # Version 004
    """List Assets"""
    response_list = client.get_asset_children(assetid)
    assets = response_list.results

    global assets_dict  # Create a global variable for assets dictionary
    assets_dict = {}  # Create the empty assets dictionary

    for item in assets:
        if item['type'] == 'folder':
            all_folders.append(item['name'])
            get_subassets(item['id'])
            # print("It's a folder: ", item['name'])
        if item['type'] == 'file':
            all_files.append(item['name'])
            # print("It's a file:   ", item['name']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("root")

for item in path.glob("**"):
    if item.is_dir():
        print(item)
```

Output (with a mockup "root" dir containing subfolders):

```
root
root\a
root\a\deeper
root\a\deeper\even deeeeeper
root\b
root\c
root\c\foo
```

Comment: Sadly doesn't seem to work.

`def get_subassets(assetid): # Version 003
    """List Assets"""
    response_list = client.get_asset_children(assetid)
    assets = response_list.results

    path = Path(assets)

    for item in path.glob("**"):
        if item.is_dir():
            print(item['name'])
`

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Comment: Also just to be save I try to find a version that could also work with Python 2.7 in case I have to use it because of my software limitations.